# Como guardar en una variable javascipt un Json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

hola chic@s tengo un problema. Estoy diseñando una web en la cual utilizo un script echo en php que busca en varios directorios de mi web imagenes que cumplan con ciertos caracteres en su nombre, y una vez lo tiene este devuelve el enlace en formato json.

Mi problema es cuando creo un codigo javascipt que consta de una funcion que mediante ajax recupera ese enlace y lo quiero guardar en una variable. He probado con async:false y tambien creando una funcion fuera del ajax y llamarla desde el ajax para guardar la variable pero no consigo hacerlo. Estoy bloqueado y no se como continuar. Alguien me puede arrojar algo de luz.

Un saludo y gracias

----EDITO-----

No puse el código ya que pense que era innecesario. Yo lo plantee de la siguiente forma:

Cuando en cualquier parte necesito que busque la imagen mediante js lo llamo en una funcion de javascript:

```
buscar_imagen(atributo);
```

y el ajax que busca la imagen en cuestion

```
function buscar_imagen(atributo){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'buscar_imagen.php?ruta='+atributo[0]+'&id='+atributo[1],
    crossDomain: true,
    scriptCharset: 'UTF-8',
    cache:false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
       variable_global=data;
    },
    error: function () {
       variable_global='url_alternativa';
    }
   });
 return variable_global;
 }
```

Como se puede deducir lo que quiero es que cuando llamo a buscar_imagen() esta me devuelva el enlace que necesito.

Gracias

Comment: Hola bro, como has de saber, es mejor poner tu codigo de lo que llevas y especificar que quieres y cual es la falla, para asi, poder tomar el codigo, hacerle las maniulaciones necesarias y poner una buena respuesta

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Cuál es el problema? Explica un poco dónde te falla o qué es lo que hace la función cuando la llamas

Comment: Cual es el problema exacto de la función?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única forma de devolver los datos desde la función sería realizar una llamada síncrona en lugar de una llamada asíncrona, pero eso congelaría el navegador mientras espera la respuesta.

Debes implementar una CallBack, adjunto el link de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Según el ejemplo que dan ahí tienes:

```
function testAjax(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    url:"getvalue.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      handleData(data); 
    }
  });
}
```

Modificada

```
testAjax(function(output){
  // acá sacas el resultado
});
```

Sería esto:

```
buscar_imagen(function(atributo){

})
```

Comment: lei ese post pero no me quedo muy claro, pero quizas estaba haciendo algo mal. Volvi a probar y fue la solucion, gracias.